# mysql: query table using only one field of a multi-field index

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a large mysql table(0.5 billion rows) that initially has one index because I have a program that filters on it:

```
KEY `id_agent_ip` (`agent_ip`)
```

At one point, I have another program that always filter on two fields, `agent_ip` and `ds_index`. In order to speed up the queries I changed my index to:

```
KEY `id_agent_ip_ds_index` (`agent_ip`,`ds_index`)
```

This solves my problem for querying two fields at the same time, but my original program that only queries for `agent_ip` runs like **4 times slower**.

My question is: If I have multi-field index and only one field is used in the `WHERE` statement, does mysql fall back to table scan? Or is it because mysql needs to load more data? I did an `explain` on the same query for both tables and the result shows:

```
+----+-------------+-------------------------------+------+----------------------+----------------------+---------+-------+---------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table                         | type | possible_keys        | key                  | key_len | ref   | rows    | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------------------------------+------+----------------------+----------------------+---------+-------+---------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | double_column_index_table     | ref  | id_agent_ip_ds_index | id_agent_ip_ds_index | 768     | const | 7159997 | Using where | 
+----+-------------+-------------------------------+------+----------------------+----------------------+---------+-------+---------+-------------+
```

and

```
+----+-------------+---------------------------+------+---------------+-------------+---------+-------+---------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table                     | type | possible_keys | key         | key_len | ref   | rows    | Extra       |
+----+-------------+---------------------------+------+---------------+-------------+---------+-------+---------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | single_column_index_table | ref  | id_agent_ip   | id_agent_ip | 768     | const | 6342786 | Using where | 
+----+-------------+---------------------------+------+---------------+-------------+---------+-------+---------+-------------+
```

I couldn't related the explain output to the performance issue except the fact that `double_column_index_table` seems to exam more rows than `single_column_index_table`, so I need some help to understand that.

Another question would be: would it make sense to create two separate indexes, one on `agent_ip` and another on `ds_index`? I would try that but at the mean time if someone could explain the theory behind it would be great.

Comment: With that large a table, be sure to run the query twice to avoid I/O caching issues.  (The `EXPLAIN` implies that it did work.)

Comment: Do you have `VARCHAR(255)` for a simple IP address??  Only 39 is needed.

Comment: Even worse:  Why is it declared `CHARACTER SET utf8`?